# PHP and MySQL insert into multiple tables from one form

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am creating a simple site to keep records of users, customers, suppliers, etc.

I have created the forms to register clients and users using single forms capturing data through $ _POST form method

So far I have not had problems since the INSERTS are done on singles table which PK is an AutoIncremented field

In the code shown below, my goal is to let users create a vendor (name, phone number, email, address) as well as assign 1 or many vendor-category. This information is contained in one form

vendors, vendors-categories, users, etc. are stored in a MySQL database with the structure shown:

[image: structure]

There is something wrong about my code after successfully create vendor and I am not sure how to solve the part that manages insertions in the join table (tblprovxrubro)

Code

```
<?php

    session_start();
    //available for admin, power-users and role-4
    if ($_SESSION['rol'] ==2) {
      header("location: ./");
    }
    include "../conexion.php";


    if (!empty($_POST)) {
      $alert='';
      if (empty($_POST['razonSocial'])|| empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $alert='<p class="msg_error">Vendor name and email must not be blank.</p>';

      }else{


        $razonSocial  = $_POST['razonSocial'];
        $email        = $_POST['email'];
        $domicilio    = $_POST['domicilio'];
        $telefono     = $_POST['telefono'];
        $usuario_id   = $_SESSION['iduser'];

        $query = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT * FROM tblprov WHERE razonSocial = '$razonSocial'");
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

        if ($result >0)
         {
          $alert='<p class="msg_error">vendor already exists.</p>';
         }else{
          $query_insert = mysqli_query($conection, "INSERT INTO tblprov(razonSocial, numero, domicilio, email, idUsuario)
                                                                  VALUES('$razonSocial','$telefono','$domicilio','$email', '$usuario_id')");

          if ($query_insert) 
          {
            $alert='<p class="msg_save">Vendor created succesfully.</p>';

            //Once vendor is created I need his ID in order to insert in table
            //tblprovxrubro as many records as vendor-types selected in form

            //Not sure about how to achieve this

            $queryBuscaprov = mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT id FROM tblprov WHERE razonSocial = '$razonSocial'");
            $result_prov = mysqli_fetch_array($queryBuscaProv);
            $idProv = $result_prov['id'];

            foreach ($_POST['idRubro'] as $opcionSeleccionada) 
            {
              //This INSERT should execute as many times as vendor-types selected in form
              $query2 = mysqli_query($conection, "INSERT INTO tblprovxrubro (idRubro, idProv) VALUES ('$opcionSeleccionada', '$idProv')");
            }
          }else{
            $alert='<p class="msg_error">Error creating vendor.</p>';
               }
             }
           }
           mysqli_close($conection);
         }
     ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <?php include "includes/scripts.php"; ?>
        <title>Registro de Proveedores</title>

    </head>
    <body>
    <?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>
        <section id="container">
        <div class="form_register" name="form_register">
          <h1><i class="fas fa-building"></i> Vendor List</h1>
          <hr>

        <form action="" method="post" class="form_register">

            <div class="alert"><?php echo isset($alert) ? $alert : ''; ?></div>
            <label for="razonSocial">Razón Social</label>
            <input type="text" name="razonSocial" id="razonSocial" placeholder="Razón Social">
            <label for="telefono">Número Telefónico</label>
            <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Número Telefónico">
            <label for="domicilio">Domicilio</label>
            <input type="text" name="domicilio" id="domicilio" placeholder="Domicilio">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">

            <?php
              $query_rubro = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT * FROM tblrubros");
              mysqli_close($conection);
              $result_rubro = mysqli_num_rows($query_rubro);
             ?>
             <select name="rubro[]" id="rubro" multiple size="12">

          <?php
            if($result_rubro > 0)
            {
              while ($rubro = mysqli_fetch_array($query_rubro)) 
              {
                ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $rubro["idRubro"]; ?>"><?php echo $rubro["rubroDescripcion"] ?></option>
                <?php
              }
            }
           ?>
        </select>
        <p>press Ctrl in order to select multiple options.</p>
        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn_save"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> Crear Proveedor</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    </section>

    <?php include "includes/footer.php"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

conection.php

```
<?php

    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = 'mypass';
    $db = 'compras';

    $conection = @mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
    mysqli_set_charset($conection,"utf8");

    if(!$conection){
        echo "connection error";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Hugo please use prepared statements, you code right now is prone to sql injection.

Comment: can you expand on "something wrong"? What are the results/errors?

Comment: will come back in a while and answer this

Comment: first you need to prone your results against sql injection. Secondly instead of using else if statement to check if your first query is ok before applying the second one. I suggest you use the transaction mechanism with multi queries that only commit your queries if all are correct, If not you rollback. [multi_queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php), [transaction](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php)